# Connection to posgres database is closing when many notifications are generated

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a thread that listens for postgres notifications and then sends the to be processed by my .NET Core application. When an action happens on the database that causes a lot of notifications the NPgSQLConnection to the database closes.

The code for listening for notifications is as follows. It is executed inside a hosted service.

```
public async Task WaitForNotificationEvent(int timeout)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (_connection)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("Notification connection to the database is unexpectantly closed");
                            // If the connection has been closed we must reopen it and listen for the known notifications.
                            foreach (var channel in _channels)
                            {
                                _logger.LogWarning($"Attempting to resubscribe to '{channel}' notifications");
                                Listen(channel);
                            }
                        }

                        _connection.Wait(timeout);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

In the code above, I do not expect to see the unexpected connection closed message. However when many notifications come through, I do.

In the postgres log I have found could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please post the exact exception being caught?

Comment: The exception message that I receive in the catch is "Exception while reading from stream"

Comment: at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()

Comment: Can you please post the *full* exception, i.e. the results of ToString() on the exception object? This includes the *full* stack trace (all methods) as well as any inner exceptions (which are likely to contain the relevant information here).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as stated here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2337

I have finally got it working.

There was a timeout when there was a lot of notifications to retrieve.

After searching around the net I found that you can set the timeouts on the NPgSQLConnection.

I don't know exactly what setting fixed it but I set the following connection settings:

```
CommandTimeout = 0
InternalCommandTimeout = 0
KeepAlive = 30
Pooling = false
TcpKeepAlive = true
Timeout = 0
```